# Can't delete pyinstaller.exe, even as admin

Tags: windows-10, permissions, python, file-permissions, administrator

I accidentally installed 32-bit python, and after uninstalling it, when I tried to delete `C:\Python27\`, and I was able to delete everything except `C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe`. Even when I try to uninstall it as an administrator, it tells me I require permission from the computer's administrator to delete it.

Advanced security settings as myself:
[image]

Advanced security settings as administrator:
[image]

Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: Take ownership of the file, then grant yourself Full Control permission to the file...then delete it.

Comment: @Twisty But how

Comment: Click `Change` to the right of Owner (first screen shot)

Comment: @Twisty It wouldn't let me. After a reboot, I could delete the file though.

Comment: In that case the file must have been in use by another process. Glad that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, something funny happened with the `pyinstaller` `exe`, and after a reboot I could delete it.